# Multithreading issue can't wait for thread to finish

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I am having problem with multithreading.
When I am tring to use wait() and notify() or join() I am getting InterruptedException.
I have 2 threads in a WHILE loop and I want to wait until both of them are finished.
this is my code:

```
while (!GamePanel.turn)
    {
        if(GamePanel.s.isRunning)
        {
            synchronized (GamePanel.s.thread) 
            {
                try {
                    GamePanel.s.thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        //Player selected random moves
        if(GamePanel.selectedMove == 1)
        {
            //Get computer's Random move.
            strategy.getRandomMove();
        }
        else
        {
            //Player selected AI moves
            if(GamePanel.selectedMove == 2)
            {
                //Get computer's AI move.
                strategy.getMove();
                System.out.println(strategy.move);

            }
        }


        //Perform the next move of the computer.
        Rules.makeMove(GamePanel.dimples, strategy.move, false);
    }
```

both strategy.getMove() and Rules.makeMove() are threads.
for each thread I've created my own start() and stop() methods :

```
public void start() 
//This function starts the thread.
{
    if (!isRunning) 
    {
        isRunning = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        thread.start();
    }
}
private void stop() 
//This function stops the thread.
{
    isRunning = false;
    if (thread != null) 
    {
        thread.interrupt();
    }
    thread = null;
}
```

I have also tried to do thread.stop() but still same problem.
**My question is how can I make the WHILE loop to wait until both threads are done??**

Comment: your stop method does not stop the thread it interrupts the thread. Or at least it looks like that. Can you show your code in the thread run method?

Comment: public void run()
{
 //Some code

 thread.sleep(delayAfterMove);

 //Some code

 stop();

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider to switching your code to use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).  You would create the latch like the following and all 3 threads would share it:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
```

Then your two threads would decrement the counter as they finish:

```
countDown.countDown();
```

And your waiting thread would do:

```
countDown.await();
```

It would be awoken after both of the threads finish and the latch goes to 0.

Comment: I don't understand where should I used it?

Comment: Instead of `GamePanel.s.thread.join();` you would do maybe `GamePanel.countDown.await();`.  Both of your game threads and the 3rd thread need to share that latch @Ron537.

Comment: Still same problem
java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(Unknown Source)
 at Mancala.Computer.DoStep(Computer.java:28)
 at Mancala.Sleep.run(Sleep.java:94)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: @Ron537 maybe is your stop method?

Comment: Is sometthing calling `stop()` that shouldn't @Ron537?  Something is interrupting the thread which is waiting.

Comment: If i delete the stop() method everything is messed up...
Is there anyway to make wait() notify() and join() work?

Comment: Sorry @Ron537.  Without more information we can't help.  I'd recommend using `System.out.println(...)` messages to help you figure out what's going on.